# How do I redirect to the success screen after receiving the "payment_intent.succeeded" event via webhook?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

**How do I redirect to the success screen after receiving the "payment_intent.succeeded" event via webhook?**

・ How can I display the success screen after making a payment with PaymentIntent?

・Checkout new allows you to specify 'success_url' as shown below, but how to specify 'success_url' if you do not use Checkout?

```
$checkoutSession = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
'customer_email' => 'customer@example.com',
'success_url' => 'https://xxxx/thanks.php',
```

---

**Code tried (PHP)**

・ I can receive "payment_intent.succeeded" event by webhook

・ I do not redirect to the success screen

▼index.php

```
<?php
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_xxxx");
$paymentintent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
  "amount" => 1099,
  "currency" => "jpy",
]);
?>
<input id="cardholder-name" type="text">
<div id="card-element"></div>
<button id="card-button" data-secret="<?php echo $paymentintent->client_secret; ?>">
  Submit Payment
</button>

<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script>
const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_xxxx');

const elements = stripe.elements();
const cardElement = elements.create('card');
cardElement.mount('#card-element');

const cardholderName = document.getElementById('cardholder-name');
const cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
const clientSecret = cardButton.dataset.secret;

cardButton.addEventListener('click', async (ev) => {
  const {paymentIntent, error} = await stripe.handleCardPayment(
    clientSecret, cardElement, {
      payment_method_data: {
        billing_details: {name: cardholderName.value}
      }
    }
  );

  if (error) {
    // Display error.message in your UI.
    console.log(error)
  } else {
    // The payment has succeeded. Display a success message.
    console.log("ok")
  }
});
</script>
```

---

**2019/4/27 add**

・case1.An example of ”header location” written in index.php. Failure

```
  if (error) {
    console.log(error)
  } else {
    <?php
      header('Location: http://example.com/');
      exit();
    ?>
  }
```

・case2.An example of ”header location” written in webhook.php. Failure

```
$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
$event = null;

try {
  $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
    $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
  );
} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
  // Invalid payload
  http_response_code(400); // PHP 5.4 or greater
  exit();
} catch(\Stripe\Error\SignatureVerification $e) {
  // Invalid signature
  http_response_code(400); // PHP 5.4 or greater
  exit();
}

if ($event->type == "payment_intent.succeeded") {
  $intent = $event->data->object;
  header('Location: http://example.com/');
  exit();
```

Comment: Have you already tried Header("Location: https://example.com/success");?

Comment: Where do I write? index.php? Or, webhook.php.
I added the content I tried to the question text.

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect the user in a webhook as it's triggered by the Stripe servers.

What you should do is when the payment succeed (in your javascript), redirect the user to a page while waiting for the event to be processed.

When you receive the webhook, change the "state" of the cart/order/etc and then the waiting page receives a websocket event or simpler, pulling requests that indicate the payment has been processed and shows the order confirmation page.